# MS Access combobox syntax error

Tags: ms-access

still new to this, I wanted to add a combobox to my sql statement and keep getting an error. Can someone explain how to fix and how to add more combobox statements. I have about 20 columns, just testing one at a time.

```
Private Sub btn_Add_Click()

CurrentDb.Execute _
   "INSERT INTO IPA_Raw_Data([Date], Auditor, Line_Clearance) " & _
   "VALUES (#" & Format(Me!txt_Date.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#,'" & _ 
   Me!txt_Name.Value & "','" & Me!cb_LC.Value & "')"

btn_Clear_Click
```

Comment: First of all, you should always give exact details of any error you get, including numbers and text, and which line the error is happening on.  If you don't know the line that throws the error, you can place a breakpoint (or click Debug on some error messages), then use the VBA IDE commands to step through the code (e.g. press F8).

Comment: What do you mean by "combobox statements"?  If you need to add more columns to a query, you would follow the same pattern for 3 columns that you already have.  Same pattern for 5, 10 or 20.

Comment: There are perhaps other techniques that would be more natural within Access, like **binding** a table or query to a form.  There are many options for controlling precisely how you want a query to be displayed, whether or not it accepts edits or new records, etc.  Although it is sometimes necessary, you may not need to explicitly code all your insert statements like you have demonstrated.

Comment: When you do need to execute a SQL statement with user parameters (i.e. from controls on a form), you really should use a temporary QueryDef with SQL parameters.  A temporary Querydef is defined without a name like `Currentdb.CreateQueryDef("", "PARAMETERS NewDate DateTime, ...; INSERT ...")`.  The parameter values will be properly formatted without having to worry about delimiters (#...#, '...') and naturally handles **null values** which your code does not.

Comment: Even though you can use reserved words as column names by wrapping them in brackets, like `[Date]`, it is highly discouraged.  It is easy to forget the brackets which can result in deceiving errors and frustration.  There are also some subtle bugs that can arise within Access when it parses SQL with such column names.  If you created the table within the Access designer, is should have warned you about such names.  Heed those warnings.  Rename your columns.

Comment: Finally, I added so many comments because without an exact error to focus on, all of those things jumped out at me, but none of them justify an actual "answer" because they are just debugging and best practice issues that are likely covered in other questions.  I hope this feedback helps and best of luck!

Comment: One thing I always will do. Take your query and write it using the graphical qury designer *gasp* but it is access guys. Then just copy paste it in. Just wondering, what are all the single 'quotes' for?  Also looking at your statement, you might  benefit from a semicolin at the end?

Comment: If `Line_Clearance` is numeric, remove the single quotes wrapping `cb_LC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work! I'm sorry for the delayed response and thank you guys for input. It was just syntax of the way I entered it.

Private Sub btn_Add_Click()

```
CurrentDb.Execute _
    "INSERT INTO IPA_Raw_Data(Date_IPA, Auditor, Area, Operator, Safely, LineClearance, PPE, VerifyDoc, GVI, CompBefore, NonConf, ProcSteps, Trained, Points, Comments) " & _
    "VALUES ('" & Me.txt_Date.Value & "', '" & Me!txt_Name.Value & "', '" & Me!txt_Area.Value & "', '" & Me!txt_Operator.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_Safe.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_LC.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_PPE.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_VDP.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_GVI.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_CBF.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_NC.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_ProStep.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_TrainProc.Value & "', '" & Me!txt_Points.Value & "', '" & Me!txt_Comment.Value & "')"


btn_Clear_Click
```

End Sub